# ThreadStatic in powershell class

Tags: multithreading, powershell

I am trying to use ThreadStaticAttribute in a powershell singelton class to create a new instance of the object for each thread but is not working.

```
class log {
    [ThreadStaticAttribute()]
    static [log] $logging;
    log(){
    }
     static [log]GetInstance(){
        if($null -eq [log]::logging){
            [log]::logging=[log]::New()         
        }
        return [log]::logging
    }
}
```

This returns the same object for newly created threads instead of instantiating a new one. Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

I've had no reason to try this, but it did come up for me a long while back. The resource I use to get a handle on it was the below, but again, I never really did this, because things changed and no reason to.

[ThreadStatic Attribute](https://blogsprajeesh.blogspot.com/2008/09/threadstatic-attribute.html)

> The [ThreadStatic]attribute indicates that the variable has one
>   instance for each  thread. This is a variation of the static
>   variables.
>
> Static variables have one instance throughout the lifecycle of the
>   program. A  variable marked with [ThreadStatic]has one instance per
>   thread in the program.
>
> See the example for more details.

```
class Program 
{
    public static Int32 singleton = 0;

    [ThreadStatic]

    public static Int32 threadSingleton = 0;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program executingProgram = new Program();
        Thread firstThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(executingProgram.FirstThread));
        Thread secondThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(executingProgram.SecondThread));
        firstThread.Start();
        firstThread.Join();
        secondThread.Start();
        firstThread.Join(); 
        Console.Read();
    }

    public void FirstThread()
    {
        singleton++;
        threadSingleton++;
        Console.WriteLine("Singleton = {0} ThreadSingleton = {1}", singleton.ToString(), threadSingleton.ToString());
    }

    public void SecondThread()
    {
        singleton++;
        threadSingleton++;
        Console.WriteLine("Singleton = {0} ThreadSingleton = {1}", singleton.ToString(), threadSingleton.ToString());
    } 
}

# Output
Singleton = 1 ThreadSingleton = 1
Singleton = 2 ThreadSingleton = 1
```